# Keyboard hiding the growing UItextview in Autolayout. How to overcome this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, keyboard, uitextview

I need to implement a chat feature in my app. In that I have a InputView as shown in the figure.

**`Image 1`**

[image]

**`Image 2`**

[image].

InputView is the `blue Coloured View` with left and right buttons and a textview.

1. On clicking a textfield this input view should scroll up and the keyboard should be coming up. And this textview is a growing textfield with the number of texts in it.
2. But When I type more than one line in the textfield. The both InputView and Textfield is growing but it is slightly hidden under the keyboard as shown below how to over come it???

**`Image 3`**

[image]

**

> And I used this code

**.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications];
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];


}
- (void)deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, self.inputView.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.inputView.frame animated:YES];
    }

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGSize sizeThatShouldFitTheContent = [textView sizeThatFits:textView.frame.size];
    //chatView_heightConstraint is the inputview height
    self.chatView_heightConstraint.constant = MIN(sizeThatShouldFitTheContent.height + 8, 87);

    CGRect _f = self.textView.frame;
    _f.size.height = MIN( self.textView.contentSize.height, 79.0);
    self.textView.frame = _f;
}
```

Comment: Try another libary https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Comment: No bro I dont want to use third party library !!! What changes do i need to do here inorder to overcome this !!!

Comment: ok then take care frame.y position of superview of uitextview.

Comment: where did you assign the input accessory view ?

Comment: I dint use accessory view

Comment: You should change the textViewDidChange: function to move up the textfield while changing the height. You should change also the size and position of all the block that contains the textField. Check out this gitHub project https://github.com/fphilipe/PHFComposeBarView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the Issue... Added a View after the scroll View and the trick works!!! `ScrollView --> UIView --> TableView and InputView`